# jump mark mid on ybar starts and ends on x tick and covers only half of the first and last bar

Tags: pgfplots

I have this problem on a graphic, i need to do it exactly so, but the jump mark mid starts from the tick, i would like it to cover the whole bar as it does for the others. The only solution i could think of is to add a first and last empty bars but still i don't know how to make the node and bars invisible..
here's the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,height=10cm,
legend entries={Nord, Sud, Est, Ovest, Media},
%ylabel={\%},
symbolic x coords={Alimentari,Gastronomie,Macellerie,Discount,Ipermercati,Supermercati~grandi,Supermercati~piccoli,Ingrossi,Altro},
every node near coord/.style={font=\large },
every node near coord/.append style={yshift=1mm,
/pgf/number format/fixed,
/pgf/number format/precision=1
},
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
ymin=-1,
xtick pos=left,
ytick pos=left
]
\addplot[jump mark mid, blue, very thick, line legend] table[x={esercizio}, y={Nord}] {scostamentotipoes.dat};
\addplot[jump mark mid,red, very thick, line legend] table[x={esercizio}, y={Sud}] {scostamentotipoes.dat};
\addplot[jump mark mid,green, very thick, line legend] table[x={esercizio}, y={Est}] {scostamentotipoes.dat};
\addplot[jump mark mid,yellow, very thick, line legend] table[x={esercizio}, y={Ovest}] {scostamentotipoes.dat};
\addplot[ybar,bar width=30, black, very thick, area legend, nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}] table[x={esercizio}, y={Media}] {scostamentotipoes.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

i'd be grateful if you can help me. I'm not very expert in pgf though...
[image: graphic image]
Thanks

Here's a simplyfied example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend entries={subset, mean},
symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
xtick pos=left,
ytick pos=left,
ymin=0,
]
\addplot[
jump mark mid,
blue, very thick, line legend] coordinates{(A,1) (B,2) (C,1.5)};
\addplot[ybar,bar width=30, black, very thick, area legend, nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}] coordinates{(A,2) (B,3) (C,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

anyway i found the solution by myself (guess i was just tired...)
by replacing "jump mark mid" with a simple line mark

```
only marks, mark=-, mark size=16,
```

Comment: Hi Alessandro, welcome to the site! It would be great if you could turn your code into a self-contained minimal example document so others can just copy and paste the code and then successfully compile it. In this case, that means adding a preamble `\documentclas{article}...` and replacing the data file with some inline dummy data.

Comment: Hi, sorry it was my first post and got it wrong. just edited but i found the solution by myself at night.. compliments for the site it's truly helpful! bye

Answer (score 1):

just for closing the post..
the obvious solution that worked for me was using a simple line mark instead of jump mark mid.
replacing

```
jump mark mid,
```

with

```
only marks, mark=-, mark size=16,
```